# error printing value to screen. Max Min values

Tags: c

I am writing an easy code that takes two numbers I enter and tells me which is the Max value and which is the Min value using  2 separate files for functions. here is my code so far. It scans the number and has the correct Max Min but when I go to print the values a crazy number prints.

```
#include<stdio.h>

 int main(void)
 {
     double num2, max, min, num1;

 printf("enter any space-separated pair of decimal numeric values on the same line: ");
 scanf("%le%le", &num1, &num2);


 max = ComputeMaximum(num1, num2);
 min = ComputeMinimum(num1, num2);


 printf("%le", max); 
 printf("%le", min);

return 0;
}
```

this is my main program, on seperate files in the same project I have:

```
double ComputeMinimum(double num1, double num2) {

    double result;

    result = (num1 < num2) ? num1 : num2;

    return result;
}
```

And

```
double ComputeMaximum(double num1, double num2) {

    double result;

    result = (num1 > num2) ? num1 : num2;

    return result;
}
```

I would like to have it print to screen:
ComputeMinimum(?, ?) returned ?
ComputeMaximum(?, ?) returned ?  (question marks are the values.)

Comment: What do you define as crazy number prints?

Comment: Something like this
`printf("ComputeMinimum(%f, %f) returned %f", num1, num2, min);
printf("ComputeMaximum(%f, %f) returned %f", num1, num2, max);`
?

Comment: Also, you can skip assigning to `result` before returning alltogether. You can just return the logical statement you have thats currently assigned to result.

Comment: min -858993460.00000000 double
  max -858993460.00000000 double

Comment: try printing `num1` and `num2` and check if you read them correctly

Comment: I don't remember the details of scanf, but how does it know where one number ends and the other begins? wouldn't it be better to read them in separately?

Comment: @BobMoore A space in between them will delimit them.

Comment: try swapping `%le` for `%lf`

Comment: Seems to work for me.  Can you copy/paste the program input and output into your question?  That will go a long way toward troubleshooting.

Comment: enter any space-separated pair of decimal numeric values on the same line: 4 8 -858993460.000000-858993460.000000Press any key to continue . . . this is my output. I do not want these crazy numbers but I do want the numbers i entered listed min and max

Comment: @BeyelerStudios "code above works as expected" except you did not do the same.  OP has `ComputeMinimum()` is a separate file and possibly no  prototype in the file with `main()`.  Suspect lack of prototype in the main file is the root of the problem.

Comment: Add `double ComputeMinimum(double num1, double num2); double ComputeMaximum(double num1, double num2);` function prototypes before `main()`.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios An older compiler will assume the return type is `int` and arguments are `int`-like.  With C99 it should at least raise a warning - depends on compiler and settings.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios C: programming on a tightrope without a net.  No problem if you do not fall.

Comment: Thanks!! @chux it worked!!

Comment: Idea for future posts.  Rather than "a crazy number prints", post what you typed (the input), the true output and the expected output.  Calling the numbers crazy is not clear.

Comment: @BobMoore `scanf()` "knows" when a FP number ends by when it  has no more valid input characters for a FP format.  `" -123.456e78-123.456e78\n"` will read in nicely as 2 FP numbers both about `-1.23456e80`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code is missing prototypes.

That is all, format is OK, functions are OK.

```
#include<stdio.h>

// Add these to the same file as main() 
// Or better yet, add to another file Compute.h and #include "Compute.h" 
// here and in the the separate C file
double ComputeMinimum(double num1, double num2);
double ComputeMaximum(double num1, double num2);

int main(void)
  ...

  // suggest adding check
  if (2 != scanf("%le%le", &num1, &num2)) {
    puts("Input error");
    return -1;
  }
```