# C programming comparing floats

Tags: c, floating-point

Where is the error in my code, super simple yet the comparisons are not outputting the correct values.
This function below is in its own file called: FloatingPointRepresentationsFunctions.c

```
int FloatCompare(float number1,float number2){
    // Write the function to compare and return the corresponding value
    if(number1 < number2){
        return -1;
    }else if(number2 < number1){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The functions should return -1 if float 2 is greater then float 1, it should return 1 if float 1 is greater then float 2. It then should return 0 if the float values are equal.

My eclipse console output(mingW):

```
number1: 12.000000 
number2: 11.000000 
Comp: -1
11.000000 is greater than 12.000000
```

and here is my main c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float number1 = 0;
    float number2 = 0;

    int comparison;

    number1=12;
    number2=11;
    printf("number1: %f \nnumber2: %f \n", number1, number2);
    comparison=FloatCompare(number1,number2); // Compare two floating point numbers
    printf("Comp: %d\n", comparison);
    if(comparison==1){
            printf("%f is greater than %f\n",number1,number2);
    }else if(comparison==-1){
                printf("%f is greater than %f\n",number2,number1);
    }else if(comparison==0){
        printf("Number are equal\n");
    }else{
        printf("Error\n");
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show the failed test case.

Comment: You describe what it should do, but how does it fail?

Comment: added the image of output

Comment: Please include the output in your question *as text*.

Comment: Or better yet as unit test / method call with commented output

Comment: Ok added my output as text

Comment: Your `FloatCompare` function looks ok.  The error must be in the code that's calling it. Show us that.

Comment: I added the rest of my code, sorry I am new to stack overflow!

Comment: This still doesn't show the problem.  Please post a complete compilable program that you've compiled and run yourself that exhibits the problem.

Comment: The code is still not complete. I suspect you do not have a proper prototype for FloatCompare. Add debugging statements to FloatCompare to print the numbers received.

Comment: Are these functions in two different files?  If so, you don't have a prototype defined for `FloatCompare`.

Comment: yes the main function is in a different file then the floatcompare function. i added the proper code above.

Comment: When declaring a float number there are two requirements; 1) there must be a decimal point  2) the number must be followed by the character `f`.   Without those details, the compiler must make a implicit conversion,  and bad things can happen,.

Comment: there is a major problem in that the prototype for the `FloatCompare()` function is not in the main.c file.  (really should be a header file for the file that contains the FloatCompare() function, which contains all the prototypes for the functions in file:  `FloatingPointRepresentationsFunctions.c`.  This header file must be #include'd in the main.c file. Otherwise, the compiler, when compiling main.c will assume all the variables are `int` not `float`.

Comment: the typical compare function is `return (n1 > n2) - (n1 < n2);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error printing value to screen. Max Min values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35203825/error-printing-value-to-screen-max-min-values)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your main file doesn't have a proper prototype for `FloatCompare`.  This means it assumes the default function definition of `int FloatCompare()`, which results in the function being called incorrectly and [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to add a declaration to your main source file so it knows how to call the function properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int FloatCompare(float number1,float number2);

int main()
{
...
}
```

Comment: Wow even though the function is in another file I must create a prototype in my main file? Well you seemed to fix the problem! Thanks

Comment: @KBro The prototype is **especially** needed with the function in another file.  Otherwise there's no way to know the proper parameters and return type.

Comment: @KBro: Not "even though" but "especially as".  If you don't have a prototype in scope, C promotes the `float` arguments to `double` and passes two `double`s to the function.  The function thinks it will be called with two `floats`, so it looks at half the first `double` as one `float` and the other half as the other `float` (and completely ignores the second value), and you don't get the expected results.  You should compile with options that tell you when you don't have a prototype in scope — it's an error in C99 and C11 (and you should avoid using C89/C90, but those compilers have options).

Comment: Your compiler would probably warn you about these things with /Wall :)

Comment: gcc will give a warning even without `-Wall` or `-Wextra`.

Comment: I have -wall and -wextra enabled and no errors. Although eclipse has been really buggy with me lately. I prefer codeblocks, but our teacher insists on eclipse.